Hardhat Error, deployer.getBalance()
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  const tokenContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    "SimpleDeFiToken"
  );
  const token = await tokenContractFactory.deploy();
  console.log("Simple DeFi Token Contract Address: ", token.address);
  console.log("Deployer: ", deployer.address);
  console.log(
    "Deployer ETH balance: ",
    (await deployer.getBalance()).toString()
  );
}

Hi, I am attempting to deploy this test contract using Sepolia. I keep receiving the following error: TypeError: deployer.getBalance is not a function.
There is a previous thread that recommends using deployer.provider.getBalance() instead, but when attempted, I receive the following error when trying to execute the contract: TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.12.0).
Could somebody please help to resolve this issue? Thank you!

You can get the balance using ethers.provider.getBalance() and passing the address of the deployer as argument, like this:
const ownerBalance = parseFloat(ethers.formatEther(await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address)));
console.log("Deployer ETH balance: ", ownerBalance);


To resolve the issue, replace deployer.getBalance() with deployer.provider.getBalance(deployer.address). This should properly retrieve the balance of the deployer's address.
